# How can I create an algorithmicx block with special characters?

Tags: symbols, algorithms, algorithmicx

In the `algorithmicx` package, you can define your own algorithm blocks with the `\algblock` command. How can I use special characters inside the definition of such a block? I want to create a German version of the for-loop. The German word for "for" is "für". The standard approaches such as `{\"u}`, etc. don't work.

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\algblock[<block>]{für}{endfur}
\algtext*{endfur}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}
\für x
\State y
\endfur
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please show your setup and a minimal example?

Comment: Isn't it easier to do `\algrenewcommand\algorithmicfor{\textbf{für}}` and use the standard `\For` and `\EndFor`?

Comment: @egreg I wanted to get rid of the`\EndFor` part.

Comment: `\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the End tag in a For cycle, you want it in no other situation.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm}
%\usepackage{algorithmicx}% not along with algpseudocode
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}

\algrenewcommand\algorithmicfor{\textbf{für}}


\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}
\For{x}
\State y
\EndFor
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found a (rather ugly) workaround. I only use the letter "f" inside the definition and add the rest as bold text:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\algblock[<block>]{f}{endfur}
\algtext*{endfur}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}
\f\textbf{\"ur} x
\State y
\endfur
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

It works, but it's really not elegant.

Comment: At the moment your answer and question isn't helpful for other people.

Comment: @Bobyandbob Why do you believe that? It would have been helpful for me, so why shouldn't it be helpful for anybody else in a similar situation?

Comment: Because we need more informations. At least compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`(for your question & answer). Then it should be helpful.

Comment: @Bobyandbob Fixed it.